# How to Set Up MySQL on Linux to be Able to Connect to It Via mysql.mydomain.com?

Tags: mysql, linux, dns

I am not looking specifically for how to make MySQL accept remote connections - that's addressed on so many tutorials, forums, and blogs. However, they stop at making changes to the `my.cnf` configuration file where they specify the host machine's IP address on the `bind-address` setting.

I am interested for the set up that lets me connect to my MySQL NOT by the IP
address of my machine but by mysql.mydomain.com. Where (or what configuration files) do I need to set this up? Will I need to create an A record for mysql.mydomain.com (though I think that DNS records are only for port 80/443 stuff)?

No, I don't want mysql.mydomain.com to be a front-facing phpMyAdmin or the like website. I want to be able to write this instead of IP address when I connect to it from MySQL Workbench or part of a connection string from a web app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a client issue. The client (i.e. the host where the app runs) needs to be able to resolve the fully-qualified hostname into an IP address. Basically it will run the function `gethostbyname()` (in C code) and that returns the IP address.

This is the way any client would find its server, not just MySQL clients. The same thing happens when you open a browser to a website.

So the client needs to resolve 'mysql.mydomain.com'. There are at least two common ways for this to happen:

1. Edit `/etc/hosts` on the client host. This allows you to specify which IP address goes with each hostname. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html
2. Use DNS. Because it would be tedious to maintain /etc/hosts files on many app client hosts, DNS was invented. The `gethostbyname()` function automatically checks DNS if there isn't a local definition in /etc/hosts for the host you want it to resolve.

DNS is NOT only for port 80/443 connections (that is, default http/https ports). It's for *any* hostname resolution. It would be used by `ping`, or `ftp` or `mysql` client, or `ssh` or any other client that makes network connections by hostname.

Comment: I wasn't sure that DNS would also apply to other than websites, so thank you.